# have a bootstrap column shown as a slide in menu/page on mobile

Tags: twitter-bootstrap-3

I'm developing the interface for a website using bootstrap. Site has a basic 2 columns structure like this: [3][9].
I'm asked by the graphic artist that the left column is displayed on sm and xs devices as a "slide-in" page, like it is usually done for navigation. But, although this column do contain navigation, it has a more complex structure.
I've tried to search for a solution, but the subject seems to have never discussed. Maybe I've just performed the wrong search?
A solution involving jQuery would be fine, too.

Thanks in advance,

Comment: The only solution hypothesis up to now is hide the sx [3] column on mobiles and duplicate its content on a slide-in panel that's shown only on mobiles.

Comment: Hi John welcome to stack overflow. In order for people to help you please provide the relevant code and also explain what you have tried so people can better help you. Providing a [js.fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net) is also helpful.